# Formatting in Java?

Tags: java

How can I make my code

```
class Factorial {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n, c, fact = 1;  

        for ( c = 1 ; c <= 5 ; c++ ) {
            fact = fact*c;
            System.out.println(fact);
        }
    }
}
```

look like this

```
X X! 
1 1 
2 2 
3 6 
4 24 
5 120
```

Comment: You will want to look up use of `System.out.printf(...)`. The [java.util.Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) will have the details on how to use this.

Comment: Answerers.. consider using `Formater` too.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(c+" "+fact);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code.

You can have System.out.println() to print it on new line
and System.out.print() to print the things on same line.

```
class Factorial {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n, c, fact = 1;  

        System.out.println("x x!");
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= 5 ; c++ ) {
            fact = fact*c;
            System.out.println(c + " " +fact);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The lack of newlines in the sample output was due to wikitext mis-formatting.  The poster actually wants tabular output.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution:

```
private static final String TEMPLATE = "%s %s";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n, c, fact = 1;
    System.out.println(String.format(TEMPLATE, "X", "X!"));
    for ( c = 1 ; c <= 5 ; c++ ) {
        fact = fact*c;
        System.out.println(String.format(TEMPLATE, c, fact));
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer for a number of reasons

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n, c, fact = 1;


    System.out.println("X X! ");
    for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++) {
        fact = fact * c;

        System.out.println(c + " " + fact);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(c+" "+fact);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for ( c = 1 ; c <= 5 ; c++ ) {
            fact = fact*c;
            System.out.println(c + " " +fact);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Factorial {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n, c, fact = 1;
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= 5 ; c++ ) {
            fact = fact*c;
            System.out.print(c+"! = "+fact+(c==5?".":", "));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly its important that you need to understand how System.out.print(ln) works. 
Note that every object that you pass to System.out.print or every object that you concatenate with string i.e. "! "+xyz the tostring() function is called.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you are just asking about formatting the output in a line or you want some logic change:

For formatting the output in a line here is the updated code:

```
       public class Factorial {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
            int n, c, fact = 1;  

            for ( c = 1 ; c <= 5 ; c++ ) {
                fact = fact*c;
                System.out.print(fact);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: he want to print the number with it's factorial , he didn't explain it from the first , so he make you confused (didn't downvote too)